# Installing ionic and cordova on windows 10

Tags: ionic-framework, error-handling, ionic3

I have installed all these. not install Cordova. please help me 
Java SDK
ANT
Nodejs[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsG6t.jpg)
Ionic

Comment: Welcome! Please read the [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article, your question does not pass the test for [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

install Cordova with ionic

Open cmd ->  npm install -g ionic cordova

than create a project -> ionic start MyApp blank (Blank is theme name)

enter project folder name ->  ng serve